# Memory profiler for xll written in C++

Tags: c++, excel, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I have an Excel addin (compiled to xll) written in C++ that I currently suspect have some sort of memory leaks. However the leaks are relatively small in size and I can only see Excel crashing after running all the code for a few hundred times.

What would be the best memory profiler program to determine memory leaks of that kind and for that particular program, how to set up the profiler in order to get the best results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any profiler will be suitable, for example check Deleaker, especially if you are using Visual C++.

To adjust it properly, set Excel.exe as an application to debug in your project settings and just start debugging.